# Hesse matrix is negatively semidefinite if a function has a local maximum

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, analysis, derivatives

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, and let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be at least twice continuously differentiable. Also, we assume $f$ has a local maximum $a \in U$.

I now want to show that the Hesse matrix $H f(a)$ is negatively semidefinite.

My thought so far was that a proof by contradiction might be a good choice to begin with? I don't really know how, though.

Comment: Suppose it's not; find an eigenvector $x$ of $Hf(a)$ with a positive eigenvalue; use a Taylor series argument to show that for small enough $\delta>0$, $f(a+\delta x)>f(a)$.

Comment: Thanks; but could you give some more details on how this Taylor series argument works?